# 404 page not found codigniter 3.1.6

Tags: codeigniter

i am new and learning codeigniter i am trying to take a simple exercise of CRUD downloaded from the net but i am stuck on the routing. i tried my best to look the solution from previous posts and answers but failed. 
Here is my Stud_controller.php

```
 <?php 
 class Stud_controller extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
     $this->load->helper('url'); 
     $this->load->database(); 
  } 

  public function index() { 
     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 

     $this->load->helper('url'); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  } 

  public function add_student_view() { 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_add'); 
  } 

  public function add_student() { 
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

     $data = array( 
        'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
        'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
     ); 

     $this->Stud_Model->insert($data); 

     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  }
```

Here is my Stud_model.php

```
<?php 
class Stud_Model extends CI_Model {

  function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
  } 

  public function insert($data) { 
     if ($this->db->insert("stud", $data)) { 
        return true; 
     } 
  } 

  public function delete($roll_no) { 
     if ($this->db->delete("stud", "roll_no = ".$roll_no)) { 
        return true; 
     } 
  } 

  public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
     $this->db->set($data); 
     $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
     $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Here is my route.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
 $route['stud'] = "Stud_controller"; 
 $route['stud/add'] = 'Stud_controller/add_student'; 
 $route['stud/add_view'] = 'Stud_controller/add_student_view'; 
 $route['stud/edit/(\d+)'] = 'Stud_controller/update_student_view/$1'; 
 $route['stud/delete/(\d+)'] = 'Stud_controller/delete_student/$1';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

my config.php

```
 $config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

my url = http://localhost/testing/index.php/stud
but the error is 404 page not found
please help me thanks

Comment: In the router write your controller in lower case:

$route['stud'] = 'stud_controller';

Comment: i have used the 'stud_controller but still there is same error

Comment: I think this is some other kind of error, not a CI error. Looks like your server isn't working because I just test your code and it looks good https://i.imgur.com/nRDNA4L.png

Comment: can it be due to 32bit/64bit mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name of the controller. Rename the controller file `Stud.php` then change the first line of the class declaration to...

```
class Stud extends CI_Controller {
```

All the other code can remain as shown in the question except in config.php you should use

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

One side note: The model does not need a `__construct()` method.

A call to `parent::__construct()` is only needed when a child class needs to setup something for itself inside a `__construct()` method. Perhaps the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) explains it better.

Comment: very very thanks now it is working fine, i have renamed the controller to Stud.php and changed the first line. i also updated the route.php thanks again

Comment: It is really strange because you can have `_` in your controller name. As you can see from my example it works...